# Pentaho PDI nullpointer exception importing data from TXT file

Tags: nullpointerexception, pentaho, pdi

I am having this error while getting fields from a txt file - since I am very new to Pantaho, could you help me sorting this?
the file that I am using is simple training txt file tab-separated with no blank rows.

[image]

Comment: share the step definition you have used and also the file data sample.

Comment: When loading data from TSV/CSV, pentaho quite often has an issue with skipping rows in the file, since in the backend it works with indexes instead of reading headers, which can give a bit of weird errors later on in your flow if you are not familiar with this. Therefore it is better to load all columns instead of a selection of columns in the first import step. Then later in your flow you can throw them away if not needed. This 95% of the time solves your issues.